# System function to find the expression of a computed column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
exec sp_helptext 'dbo.StoredProcName'
```

(which will return the SQL code that composes a stored procedure)
but for computed columns.  Does such a function exist, outside of using SSMS to find it?
I'm looking for the text of the expression used to calculate the computed column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    name, definition
FROM sys.computed_columns
```

and of course - that catalog view also contains **a lot more** useful information in its other columns!

Comment: while poking around looking for some guidance on this question i ran across several questions which you had answered.  seeing as how you have answered previous questions of mine i think this is the perfect time to say, thanks :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: thanks - and you're welcome ! Glad if I can be of help

Answer (score 2):

The following is `sp_helptext`'s syntax:

> sp_helptext [ @objname = ] 'name' [ , [ @columnname = ]
>   computed_column_name ]

So you can do something like this:

```
 exec sp_helptext @objname = N'AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderHeader', @columnname = TotalDue
```

Source: [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx)